# conv_lstm.py example uses 'binary_crossentropy' loss for regression. Why not using 'mean_squared_error' instead?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

2 questions:

1. I was using [keras team **conv_lstm.py** example on github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/conv_lstm.py) to predict the next frame of the video created in that example. It is a regression problem obviously, since we are going to predict the next frame. I was wondering why they used this loss

   ```
   line 38:

   seq.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta')
   ```

   Instead, I believe using:

   ```
   seq.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop')
   ```

would result in better predictions, since we are implementing a regression problem, rather than classification.
Am I correct?

2. In line 107 of the code, they left a comment saying that:

> feed it with the first 7 positions and then predict the new positions.

here is the code they used to predict 7 frames given 7 input frames :

```
which = 1004
track = noisy_movies[which][:7, ::, ::, ::]

for j in range(16):
   new_pos = seq.predict(track[np.newaxis, ::, ::, ::, ::])
   new = new_pos[::, -1, ::, ::, ::]
   track = np.concatenate((track, new), axis=0)
```

Suppose I want to predict 7th frame of a test video.
If I don't feed the model with the last 7 frames, instead feed it with just the 7th frame, would it make difference in prediction?

Thanks.

Comment: Part 1 is opinion based unless you're the actual developer. Part 2: try it out. There is not much here that is on topic for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if the outputs are in the range between 0 and 1, it's totally ok to use 'binary_crossentropy'.

It's as if you had a classification problem in just one class: true or false. (The function is still continuous, though, and in the end the point of zero error will be the same)

Depending on the types of activation functions used (especially with 'sigmoid'), 'binary_crossentropy' would bring you the results way faster than 'mse' due to mathematical details.

---

An LSTM layer learns from analysing frames (or steps of any kind of data) recurrently.

It has what is called an "inner state". Every step it analyses brings an update to this inner state, so it works both like a "memory" of what happened until this point and also as some kind of positioner like "where in the movie am I now?"

Thus, having predicted the previous steps is absolutely necessary for the LSTM to give good predictions.

Imagine you never watched Star Wars before, and you start playing it at the scene where 
Dart says: "Luke, I'm your father". You'd just say: "what?".

Now watch all the movies from the beginning and reach that part. Will your understanding be different? The LSTM will agree with you.